# How to establish relationship between Images, Users and Ratings table

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database

I have following tables:

```
 a) Images (Columns : imageId{PK Int} )
 b) Users (Columns : username {PK varchar(50), ...}
 c) Ratings (Columns : imageId {FK}, username {FK}, Stars {int})
```

I want Rating table not to have any duplicate records like following:

```
1, Amigo, 5 (This is right)
1, Durango, 3 (This is right)
1, Amigo, 3 (WRONG) Amigo should not be allowed to add new record but only update
```

How can I do this from database side by establishing the relationship instead of taking care of this from application side. I don't want to make a back end call and check if this record exists and if yes please update but what I want is database to be smart not to add this by either by throwing an exception which I will catch ad update the record instead or 
if DB can just update it that would be cool. Please guide me what should I be do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a UNIQUE constraint on ImageId and UserName in the Ratings table.  Take a look at the documentation here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166.aspx

Your alter statement would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Ratings] 
ADD CONSTRAINT UNQ_Ratings UNIQUE (imageId, username)
```